# Error: Could not load template :opencart 2.1.0.1

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have opencart 2.1.0.1, with Journal template, I tried to update the journal theme to the latest version, and then refreshed the modifications, everything worked except product page it shows this error with
2017-10-30 13:54:22 - PHP Notice: Error: Could not load template /......./public_html/catalog/view/theme/product/product! in /......./public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_loader.php on line 99
I removed all the extensions and modifications and refreshed, and removed vqcache, the same no change,
I have looked at that line
it is:

```
trigger_error('Error: Could not load template ' . $file . '!');
```

I have tried to echo the $file:

```
echo '<br>'.DIR_TEMPLATE.'<br>'.$template;
```

it shows this

```
 /..................../public_html/catalog/view/theme/

 product/product
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think, You will need to contact to your custom theme authors for better solution.

Answer (score 1):

both versions framework are different old version was tpl but in new version of opencart they are using twig that's why its not working  , i will suggest you to install updated version of opencart and also setup updated version of your theme by using your old database .

Comment: Possibly add a link and some instructions on how to install the updated version of opencart, and some steps as to how to set it up to use the old database.

Comment: This is what are we doing right now, migrating to OC3, thanks